# Git 2.5 `worktree add`- keep staged file in branch after deleting temp directory

Tags: git

I like the worktree feature in Git 2.5. In repo `foobar`, I want:

1. Terminal 1 to be in branch `foo`
2. Terminal 2 to be in branch `bar`.
3. In terminal 2, while in branch foo I did `git worktree add ../bar
   origin/bar; cd ../bar` which worked out great. Terminal 2 was now in
   branch `bar`.
4. In terminal 2, I touch `apple.txt` and stage it in branch `bar`.
5. I then get out of that directory /bar and `rm -rf /bar`.
6. Then in terminal 1, I do `git checkout bar`.

However, the file `apple.txt` I created and staged in `bar` does not show up in `git status`. Why is this? Can I make it so that the file I created in `/bar` and staged stays in branch `bar` after I delete the directory? I don't want to do a push.

FYI-  I didn't do a git `git worktree prune`.

Comment: this is a git feature, not a GitHub one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A staged file is not in any branch because it is not committed yet. Adding a file to the staging area just prepares it for the next commit. You have to actually run `git commit` in order to put it into the repository (in the current branch).

Each work tree has its own staging area. Because have you deleted the work tree without committing, you have lost the changes.

Comment: I don't want to do commits..... I guess git stash is the only way still? Was hoping I could get away from git stash.

Comment: Also, since I did not do `git worktree prune` shouldn't the tree still exist?

Comment: The work tree is where the new copy of the project was checked out (the `bar` directory). `Git` keeps track of the additional work trees in the subdirectory `.git/worktrees` of the main working copy (where the local repository is also located). When you have removed the `bar` directory, the information about that work tree became invalid (it points to the directory `bar` that doesn't exist). It will be removed on the next `git worktree prune`.

Comment: Internally, `git stash` creates a hidden merge commit.